# Quick help turning sum into mean

Tags: sum, mean

I was helped earlier in creating this code that would create a histogram of a randomint. Everything looks good except I accidently had the output as a sum instead of a mean of all the numbers that were randomly chosen.I dont want to mess anything up so I was just going to ask, How can I convert this sum into a mean output instead?

```
import java.util.Random;
class Assignment4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int sum = 0;
        int[] bins = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int randomint = 1 + r.nextInt(10);
            sum += randomint;
            bins[randomint-1]++;
            //System.out.print(randomint + ", ");
        }

        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);

        System.out.println("Data shown below: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < bins.length; i++)
        {
            int binvalue = bins[i];

            System.out.print((i+1) + ": ");
            for(int j = 0; j < binvalue; j++)
            {
                System.out.print('*');
            }
            System.out.println(" (" + binvalue + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured it out.... just turned System.out.println("Sum = " + sum); into System.out.println("Mean = " + sum/100);